# Scrolling Displacement Overshoot - Mathematical Issue

Tags: math, user-interface, scroll, lua, scrollbar

So what I'm trying to do, is make a nice scroll bar, using a Kinetic Model.  The issue is dampening on over-shoot.  The behavior I want to show is that when you overshoot (Go past the max/minimum), it dampening the positioning.

The specific behavior I want is this: So say, the Maximumum Overshoot is 50 pixels. Here's a table representing how I'd like it to work.  (This is the best way, I can think of, to present it).

```
Displacement      | Position it | Percent 
of position       | Displays @  | Overshot Over
-------------------------------------------------
    25            |    12.5     |   50%
    100           |    25       |   100%
    200           |    37.5     |   200%
    400           |    43.75    |   400%
    ...                ...          ...

Note: Decimals would obviously round down so we can actually display it.
```

I'm pretty sure I can calculate this recursively (but I don't want to do that).  I think the mathematical relationship is fairly obvious, although I'm not exactly sure how to do it.  **I may even be thinking of this the wrong way,so please consider disregarding my chart.** The **important** thing is that the **user can't move the window past the max overshoot value** (In this case, 50 pixels).

Here's a segment the of code running the positioning setting...

```
function KineticModel:SetPosition(NewPosition)
    -- Set's the position of the kinetic model. Using this, it'll calculate velocity.


    local CurrentTime = tick()
    local ElapsedTime = CurrentTime - self.TimeStamp
    local LocalVelocity = ((self.Position - self.LastPosition) * 5) / ElapsedTime

    TimeStamp = CurrentTime
    self:SetVelocity((0.2 * self.Velocity) + (0.8 * LocalVelocity)) -- 20% previous velocity maintained, 80% of new velocity used.

    if NewPosition > self.Maximum then
        print("[KineticModel] - Past Max Manual")
        local Displacement = math.abs(NewPosition - self.Maximum)
        -- Dampen position so it can't go over. 

        self.Position = self.Maximum + (Displacement / self.MaxBounce) -- This doesn't work. :(
    elseif NewPosition < self.Minimum
        print("[KineticModel] - Past Min Manual")
        local Displacement = math.abs(NewPosition - self.Minimum)
        -- Same displacement here
    else
        self.Position = NewPosition
    end

    self.LastPosition = self.Position
    self.OnPositionChange(self.Position)
    print("[KineticModel] - Set Velocity @ "..self.Velocity.."; Local Velocity @ "..LocalVelocity)

end
```

The main issue is trying to find a mathematical way to find the displacement I should display it at.  I'll be implementing this displacement to basically filter out the position before it's set at every point, so if there's a potential problem with that, please tell me.

Thanks. :D

**Edit:** Title, Tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer ignores all dynamic aspects about velocities and dampening and so on. I'll concentrate on converting an overshoot value which might be arbitrarily large into a displacement value with a bounded maximal value.

## A simple formula

One simple formula with properties like you are asking for would be the following: let `x ≥ 0` be the overshoot and `0 ≤ y ≤ 50` be the resulting displacement. Then you can relate them using a formula like this:

```
y = 50*x/(x + 75)
```

The fraction `x/(x+75)` will come arbitrarily close to 1 for large `x` without ever reaching it, so your displacement will never exceed 50. You can tweak that `75` in the formula to control the speed with which it converges. For 75 you will get:

```
 x    y
 25  12.5
 50  20.0
100  28.6
200  36.4
400  42.1
```

## More flexibility

To gain even more control over shape of the curve, you could use a different formula which contains plynomials in `x` in both numerator and denominator. But I'd only do this if you have very strict requirements about the curve passing through specific points, or some other reason why the simple approach outlined above is not sufficient.

## Matching speed

The simple formula will likely cause a jerk in the way the content moves, since its speed will most likely not match that of the non-overshot document. To match speeds, you can use the one degree of freedom to control the slope. The easiest way to do this would be use the same unit for input and output, e.g. pixels. Then you'd aim for a slope of 1 at the origin.

```
y = 50*x(x + 50) = x/(x/50 + 1)
```

This will give the following values:

```
 x    y
 25  16.7
 50  25.0
100  33.3
200  40.0
400  44.4
```

## Illustration

Here is a plot of the two functions I mentioned, together with the data points from your table. Not an exact match, but it should be reasonably close. Note that for the first row of your table, I wasn't sure which colum to choose as the `x` value, so there are now two data points for `y=12.5`.

[image: Plot of function]